# SQL Server: extremely slow results when increasing top by 1

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I've a query that joins several views and one table using inner joins. No sub-queries are involved, all joined fields are indexed, and all joins are on int fields. Using "top 342" in the select clause results in a query which executes in ~2 seconds. But if I use the same query and "top 343", the query doesn't finish executing within 7 minutes. I tried several other values below 342 which also worked as expected.

Removing the joined table from the query causes the query to complete within just a few seconds no matter the value used with top.

I tried updating statistics on the table using full-scan, that didn't change anything.

Within the same context of SQL execution I use:

```
DBCC FREEPROCCACHE
GO
CHECKPOINT; 
GO 
DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS; 
GO
```

What types of things might cause the slow execution?

Comment: ...I've also run DBCC CHECKTABLE against the table, no errors were found

Comment: Maybe the 343th record in the main table has a huge number of correspondent values on the join table, so it takes forever to load them, but not the others. If this is true, it has nothing to do with the number; if this record were the first, a 'TOP 1' would take a lot of time as well.

Comment: @Doug The fields it joins upon assures a 1:1 relationship

Answer (score 1):

Changing the value of `TOP` will alter the [row goal](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/queryoptteam/archive/2006/03/30/564912.aspx).

This can have a significant effect on the rest of the plan. You might find that `TOP 342` happens to produce a plan where non blocking operators such as nested loops are favoured but for `TOP 343` SQL Server's costing model reckons it is cheaper to use a blocking operator such as hash join that consumes the whole sub tree first for example.

You could experiment with constructs such as

```
SELECT TOP 363 *
FROM your_view
OPTION (FAST 362)
```

Or

```
DECLARE @Top INT = 363

SELECT TOP (@Top) *
FROM   your_view
OPTION (optimize for (@Top = 362))
```

But these would be very much a last resort for me if unable to get a satisfactory plan any other way.

See also [Inside the Optimizer: Row Goals In Depth](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/paul_white/archive/2010/08/18/inside-the-optimiser-row-goals-in-depth.aspx)